# Kaplan-Meier plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, k-means, kaplan-meier

I have generated the following clusters. Now I want to compare 3 groups in terms of survival. I am wondering how to create 3 groups based on "scores" and draw KM plot.

Codes:[image]

```
    plot(scores[,c(1,3)],col=out$cluster,xlab='PC1',ylab='PC3',pch=1+as.numeric(scores[,1]>0) + 2*as.numeric(scores[,3]>0))
 abline(h=0);abline(v=0)
```

Comment: I do not understand what the groups are since there are four different shapes (circles, triangles and two different crosses) and two different colors. Judging by the plot I see no clear pattern that indicates 3 groups. Further, if you need a code how to put the groups back to your dataset, this question probably should rather go to stackoverflow